# How to run two thread periodically?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

I am asked  to make a Player class ( that implements runnable ) in which I implement a run method which generates a random number and waits for the method getchoice and a getchoice method which return the generated number and notifies run . then a RockPaperScissors class( that implements Runnable) which contains method run that containt two threads containing each  a player object , these two threads should play against each other 1000 times , then they should be interrupted and then it will be displayed how many times each player won . . my problem is , when my code starts to run , at the beginning it is perfect , but at a random round it starts to just play many times player 1 before going to player 2 which defeats the purpose of the game : here is the code :

```
public class RockPaperScissors implements Runnable {
int result1 ;
int result2 ;
int result3 ;

private final Object lock = new Object();

public void run(){


    synchronized(lock){
        Player a = new Player() ;   
        Player b = new Player() ;
    Thread a1 = new Thread(a) ;
    Thread b1= new Thread (b) ;
        a1.start(); 
        b1.start(); 
        int choice1 = -100 ;
    int choice2 = -1066 ;
  for (int i = 0 ; i < 1000 ; i++){



    try {

        choice1 = a.getChoice();    
    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {

    }


    try {

        choice2 = b.getChoice();

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

    }
    if (choice1 == 1 && choice2==0)
        result2++;
    else if (choice2 == 1 && choice1==0)
        result1++;
    else if (choice1 == 1 && choice2==1)
        result3++ ;
    else if (choice1 == 1 && choice2==2)
        result1++ ;
    else if (choice1 == 2 && choice2==1)
        result2++ ;
    else if (choice1 == 0 && choice2==2)
        result1++ ;
    else if (choice1 == 2 && choice2==0)
        result2++ ;
    else if (choice1 == 2 && choice2==2)
        result3++ ;
    else if (choice1 == 0 && choice2==0)
        result3++ ;


    }
```

and this is class Player :

```
public class Player implements Runnable {
private final Object lockvalue = new Object();
private int a;

public void run() {
    synchronized (lockvalue) {
        for (int counter = 0; counter < 1000; counter++) {

            java.util.Random b = new java.util.Random();
            a = b.nextInt(3);
            System.out.println(counter);
            try {
                lockvalue.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Thread player was interrupted");

            }

        }

    }
}

public int getChoice() throws InterruptedException {
    synchronized (lockvalue) {
        lockvalue.notify();
        return a;

    }

}
```

}

if my programm runs perfectly the counter display should always have the number starting from 0 to 1000 duplicated one after the other , but here it starts like that but then it gets messed up and it never reaches 1000 , it stops sometimes at 700 sometimes at 800 . all I am allowed to used is notify() , notifyAll() , wait() , start() , interrupt() and join() .

your help would be greatly appreciated . Thanks

Comment: The Runnable should only have information about who wins the game, not how many times it's played.

Comment: do you mean the runnable of RockPaperScissors ?

Comment: Yes.  If I were you, I'd forget about threads until I had the logic of the game with two players working perfectly.  Once you have that, make it multithreaded.

Comment: the logic is actually very simple without threads .... 
if I don't put how many times it's played ,  the game will not stop also I need to call getChoice() twice every round in order to read the generated number and generate the new one so a loop is necessary .

Comment: What are you exact instructions? As it stands and per my view, this does not look to contain a problem which is solved by multi-threading.

Comment: what  needs to be done is that thread 1 should play and then thread 2 should play and then a comparaison happens , and then we start again . if you actually try this code two problems will occur , first it won't play periodically meaning there wil be thread 1 thread 1 thread 1 and then thread 2 , second problem is that it never reached 1000 rounds , every time is stops at a random number and waits apparently .....

Comment: The *exact* instructions, not an abbreviation of it, and the instructions should be in your question not in comments. Also "threads" don't play -- objects do.

Comment: yes i think that's what's implied by this exercice . can you elaborate please ?

Comment: Your implementation and approach show that you don't understand concurrency, how it works and when should be applied. I recommend you to read corresponding chapter (Concurrency) in Bruce Eckel's "Thinking in Java" - http://www.mindview.net/Books/TIJ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation and approach show that you don't understand concurrency, how it works and when should be applied.

I recommend you to read corresponding chapter (Concurrency) in Bruce Eckel's "Thinking in Java" - http://www.mindview.net/Books/TIJ/

To make your code work You have to add one more wait-notify before return in Player.getChoise()

Here is fixed version:

**RockPaperScissors.java**

```
package game;

public class RockPaperScissors
{
  static int player1wins = 0;
  static int player2wins = 0;
  static int draw = 0;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
  {
    int cycles = 1000;
    Player player1 = new Player("Player-1", cycles);
    Player player2 = new Player("Player-2", cycles);

    new Thread(player1).start();
    new Thread(player2).start();


    for (int i = 0; i < cycles; i++)
    {
      Choice choice1;
      Choice choice2;

      choice1 = player1.getChoice();
      System.out.println("Value 1 is definitely generated");

      choice2 = player2.getChoice();
      System.out.println("Value 2 is definitely generated");

      System.out.printf("\n%3d\nPlayer1 - %8s\nPlayer2 - %8s\n", i, choice1.name(), choice2.name());

      if (choice1 == choice2)
      {
        draw++;
        System.out.println("Draw!");
      }
      else if (choice1 == Choice.ROCK)
      {
        if (choice2 == Choice.PAPER)
        {
          player2wins++;
          System.out.println("2 wins!");
        }
        else
        {
          player1wins++;
          System.out.println("1 wins!");
        }
      }
      else if (choice1 == Choice.PAPER)
      {
        if (choice2 == Choice.SCISSORS)
        {
          player2wins++;
          System.out.println("2 wins!");
        }
        else
        {
          player1wins++;
          System.out.println("1 wins!");
        }
      }
      else if (choice1 == Choice.SCISSORS)
      {
        if (choice2 == Choice.ROCK)
        {
          player2wins++;
          System.out.println("2 wins!");
        }
        else
        {
          player1wins++;
          System.out.println("1 wins!");
        }
      }
    }
    System.out.printf("Player 1 wins - %3d times;\n" +
        "Player 2 wins - %3d times;\n" +
        "Draw result   - %3d times\n\n", player1wins, player2wins, draw);

    System.out.printf("Player-1 cycles left = %d\n" +
        "Player-2 cycles left = %d\n", player1.getCounter(), player2.getCounter());
  }
}
```

**Player.java**

```
package game;

import java.util.Random;

public class Player implements Runnable
{
  private Random random = new Random();
  private int value;
  private int counter;
  private String name;

  public Player(String name, int cycles)
  {
    this.name = name;
    this.counter = cycles;
  }

  public synchronized void run()
  {
    while (true)
    {
      try
      {
        wait();
      }
      catch (InterruptedException e)
      {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

      value = random.nextInt(3);
      System.out.println(name + " ... Value was generated = " + value);
      notify();

      // Otherwise your thread will never stop!
      counter--;
      if (counter <= 0)
      {
        System.out.println(name + " ... Limit of operations is exceeded.");
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  public synchronized Choice getChoice() throws InterruptedException
  {
    System.out.println(name + " ... now can generate value");
    notify();
    System.out.println(name + " ... wait until value is generated");
    wait();
    Choice choice = Choice.values()[value];
    System.out.println(name + " ... returning generated value: " + value);
    return choice;
  }

  public int getCounter()
  {
    return counter;
  }
}
```

**Choise.java**

```
package game;

public enum Choice
{
  ROCK,
  PAPER,
  SCISSORS;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much . exactly what i was looking for . 
may i ask why should i do the while (true) wait() loop at run ? and why do i have to wait in getchoice ?

Comment: while loop in this case does the same job as your for loop (because of counter), but from my point of view it looks more logical.

wait in getChoice is necessary for generation of the next random value because wait() frees the monitor, stops getChoice and lets run() to execute. You can comment it out and see what will happen, that's why I have added simple log messages.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider implementing your logic using a [semaphore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) or a [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) for better synchronization

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/semaphore.html

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/countdownlatch.html